# Parâmetro action do formulário abrindo o script php

Tags: php, formulário

Meu problema é relativamente simples, tenho um formulário e preciso que: ao clicar no botão submit os dados sejam passados para um arquivo php(referenciado no parâmetro action do formulário) que irá salvar os dados em um banco de dados. No entanto quando clico no botão submit o formulário exibe o código do meu arquivo php(estou utilizando um arquivo externo para o php). O resultado esperado seria que nada fosse exibido e os dados fossem salvos no banco de dados, como eu faço isso?

Comment: Aparentemente seu arquivo PHP não está em um servidor com suporte a PHP, uma boa opção é o xampp https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html.

Comment: Eu estou utilizando o xampp, todos os arquivos estão na pasta htdocs dentro de outra pasta. Nessa pasta está o arquivo html e em outra pasta está o meu arquivo php

Comment: Segue a estrutura de pastas: https://snag.gy/xJFU19.jpg

Comment: Como você está acessando seu arquivo html? para o PHP funcionar, vc deve executar o html usando o HTTP e não o File://, em outras palavras, você não deve dar um clique duplo sobre o seu html, vc deve abrir seu browser, digitar no endereço `localhost` e navegar até seu arquivo HTML.

Comment: Certo, naveguei pelo localhost, mas quando dei submit no formulário a página a seguir foi mostrada: https://snag.gy/hpHoPL.jpg. Sei que meu código era um echo e isso deveria acontecer de qualquer forma, mas caso fosse uma query em um banco de dados outra janela seria aberta? Ou o servidor permaneceria no meu arquivo html? (no caso o que eu quero).

Comment: Aparentemente esse é o comportamento padrão, o action do form redireciona para o seu arquivo PHP, é assim mesmo, você pode dar um redirect para voltar para sua página, pode usar o `header("location:$redirect");` para isso.

Comment: Tem alguma forma de eu contornar isso, somente salvando os dados no banco de dados quando o submit for pressionado?